# How to test if the tag list is empty for the current page?

Tags: tags

I have three custom taxonomies (topic, name, simile) Currently I display the list of tags in each taxonomy *for the current post* at the bottom of the post. That works fine. But I would like to give each taxonomy a heading, but only if there is something displayed for that taxonomy.

I am currently doing a similar thing with custom fields. For example the further-reading field:

```
<?php 
    $my_furtherReading = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'further-reading', true);

    if( ! empty( $my_furtherReading ) ) {
        echo '<div class="furtherReading"><h2>Further Reading:</h2>' . $my_furtherReading . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

It only prints the heading if the field is not empty.

This is how I am displaying my taxonomies (topic taxonomy)

```
<?php
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'topic',
'', ' ', '' );
?>
```

Is there a function to test if the tag list is empty? If so, could someone be kind enough to show me how to use it?

Comment: see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/#return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) function, like this:

```php
if ( wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'topic', [ 'fields' => 'ids' ] ) ) {
    // Your code
}
```

We passed the `'fields' => 'ids'` in args, just to prevent instantiation of the full WP_Term objects in the background, since you only need to check if there are any, and using a different function for the HTML generation.

Comment: How about using [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)? :)